# JQuery Mobile Dynamic Content Disappears When Gong Back

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using JQM with AJAX transitions and loading social sharing buttons from sharethis.  No problem on initial load:

```
$( '#recipe' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = 'http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    var ss=document.getElementById("social");
    ss.innerHTML="<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\">stLight.options({publisher: \"c06b6443-3837-4409-???????\"});</script><span class='st_pinterest_large' displayText='Pinterest'></span><span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span><span class='st_twitter_large' displayText='Tweet'></span>";    
});
```

When I navigate away from this page and use the native back button, the social buttons are no longer there.  Any ideas why the JS is not being held in the page?  Thanks for any help

**UPDATE**

Tried pageshow as suggested- still same issue.  Here is the new JS

```
$( '#recipe' ).live( 'pageshow',function(event){
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.src = 'http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-???????';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};
    var soc=document.getElementById("social");
    soc.innerHTML="<div class=\"addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style\"><a class=\"addthis_button_preferred_1\"></a><a class=\"addthis_button_preferred_2\"></a><a class=\"addthis_button_preferred_3\"></a><a class=\"addthis_button_preferred_4\"></a><a class=\"addthis_button_compact\"></a><a class=\"addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style\"></a></div>";          
});
```

To reproduce issue 
1. url: http://19thway.com/cck/recipe.php?id=2 (you will see ss widgets on top left)
2. click "locate ingredients" at bottom left
3. click "back" button top left
4. no ss widgets!!!

I don't want to turn the AJAX navigation off and I tried caching the page, but the url changes so that doesn't work for me either.  Are there any other options to get the JS to refire?  Thanks.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

This is driving me crazy.  If you enter the application on the link above everything is fine.  Try this please:

1. enter here: http://19thway.com/cck/index.html
2. navigate forward to the recipe page (all is fine)
3. navigate past recipe page and then use back button (widgets gone!!!)

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you insert a piece of javascript code into the page? You can also just run the javascript code on the pageshow event... I.e. `.on('pageshow',function(event){...}`

Comment: If you are new to jQuery you should read up on the [AJAX page loading](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html), because it causes your javascript not to rerun when navigating backwards.

Comment: Erm the link you're giving us is working, pressing back I still see the SS icons - but for why pageshow is the correct answer: `pageinit` only fires once for a page and `pageshow` fires after, when you navigate away and press back on the browser to return to the first page `pageinit` won't fire again, but `pageshow` will.